# Usage of Task.WhenAll with infinite Tasks produced by BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, task, async-await, blockingcollection

I am adding Background Tasks to a Blocking Collection (added in the Background).

I am waiting with Task.WhenAll on a Enumerable returned by GetConsumingEnumerable.

My question is: Is the overload of Task.WhenAll which receives an IEnumerable "prepared" to potentially receive an endless amount of tasks?

I am simply not sure if i can do it this way or if it was meant to be used this way?

```
private async Task RunAsync(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (BlockingCollection<Task> jobcollection = new BlockingCollection<Task>())
    {
        Task addingTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var jobs = Repository.GetAllJobs();
                foreach (var job in GetRootJobsDue(jobs, utcNow))
                {
                    jobcollection.Add(Task.Run(() => RunJob(job, jobs, cancellationToken, utcNow), cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
                }

                await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
            }
        }, cancellationToken);

        await Task.WhenAll(jobcollection.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like using `Parallel.Foreach(Repository.GetAllJobs,....)` would be a simpler solution.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` will block the calling thread till `GetConsumingEnumerable` finishes

Comment: Well if there are an infinite number of tasks they'll never all finish, because you'll never get the whole set.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel GetConsumingEnumerable returns immediatelly an IEnumerable but only gets iterated when data is available... that intended behaviour

Comment: @rudimenter I edited my comment before you reply. See if that makes sense?

Comment: @Servy Thats what i want... Only return when CancellationToken is fired... (deep in some other code)

Comment: @rudimenter But `WhenAll` doesn't yield control until it has been able to enumerate all of the items in the sequence it's given.

Comment: @rudimenter Then don't use `WhenAll` at all, just wait on that cancellation token.

Comment: @L.B Nope because you still need to add the task to the Enumerable... but yes as a replacement for WhenAll

Comment: It's not even going to execute that line until the token has been cancelled... if you want to return when it gets cancelled, just remove that line altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` will not work with an infinite number of tasks. It will first (synchronously) wait for the enumerable to finish, and then (asynchronously) wait for them all to complete.

If you want to react to a sequence in an asynchronous way, then you need to use `IObservable<Task>` (Reactive Extensions). You can use a TPL Dataflow `BufferBlock` as a "queue" that can work with either synchronous or asynchronous code, and is easily convertible to `IObservable<Task>`.

Comment: Does the same apply for Parallel.Foreach. Will it also wait until the enumeration is finished?

Comment: @rudimenter `Parallel.Foreach` is an inherently synchronous operation, not an asynchronous one.  Not only will it synchronously wait for the sequence to finish, it'll synchronously wait to finish processing all of the items.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Parallel` will not immediately wait for the enumeration before starting processing, but you will "lose" a thread to the enumerating.

Answer (score 7):

[Since your goal is merely to wait until the cancellation token is cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488574/usage-of-task-whenall-with-infinite-tasks-produced-by-blockingcollection/25488865?noredirect=1#comment39782016_25488574), you should do *that*.  For reasons others have explained, using `WhenAll` on an infinite sequence of tasks isn't the way to go about that.  There are easier ways to get a task that will never complete.

```
await new TaskCompletionSource<bool>().Task
    .ContinueWith(t => { }, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: It seems his goal is to wait until all the tasks have been completed, not until they've all been created.

Comment: How does that work? `TaskCompletionSource<bool>()Task` is never going to complete which means `ContinueWith` never going to execute. I assume you mean to call `SetCancelled` on the Task?

Comment: @KyleW [No, it's not.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488574/usage-of-task-whenall-with-infinite-tasks-produced-by-blockingcollection/25488865?noredirect=1#comment39782016_25488574)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Nope, this will work as is.  When the token is cancelled it'll stop waiting for the never ending task it is a continuation of to finish.  Your approach would work to, it'd just be more lines of code.

Comment: I see, That's beautiful. I overlooked it.. +1

Comment: This would render also the BlockingCollection useless... I could simply run the Tasks in the loop in the background and just 
await addingTask

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Task.WhenAll` will try to enumerate the collection, which means that it itself will block until the collection is completed or cancelled.  If it didn't, then the code could theoretically finish `await`ing before the tasks have been created.  So there's going to be an extra block in there... it will block waiting for the threads to be created, and then block again until the tasks are done.  I don't think that's a bad thing for your code, as it's still going to block until the same point in time.